# Select image extension in Sphinx

Tags: python, pdf, svg, python-sphinx

I am currently writing documentation for my Python package using Sphinx. I have vector images that I'd like to use, but the HTML documentation only accepts SVG, while the PDF documentation only works with PDF files. No problem, I have both versions of my images.

I am trying to use the `only` directive to choose which image to include in different versions of my docs, like so:

```
.. only:: latex

    .. image:: ../docs/alpha-strat.pdf

.. only:: html

    .. image:: ../docs/alpha-strat.svg
```

And then I compile it with `make clean pdflatex html`, but Sphinx uses the PDF Image in both versions of the documentation. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the backends automatically use the image of the supported format by [replacing the image filename extension with an asterisk](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images):

```
.. image:: ../docs/alpha-strat.*
```

From the Sphinx documentation linked to above:

> Sphinx then searches for all images matching the provided pattern and
>   determines their type. Each builder then chooses the best image out of
>   these candidates.

Comment: Is this behavior new? I have done what you suggested but Sphinx still only searches for the PDF images. I have the newest version of Sphinx, but my Makefile is older, though...

Comment: Very strange. Sounds like some sort of caching issue. Is the HTML output good if you set the extension to `svg` instead of `*`?

Comment: No, it still looks for PDF files. For the record, I use `make clean html latexpdf` so all previous files are deleted.

Comment: Problem solved, answer accepted. That is the correct way of doing what I want. Thank you.